# Any finite set is a null-set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question

How can we prove that a finite set is a null-set? Maybe would it be easier to prove that the outer measure of a finite set is $0$? any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

thanks,

Comment: What measure? Start proving that a singleton set is a null set, the remainder is done by the additivity of the measure.

Comment: What is the measure space? What is the measure? If the measure is atomic, then you can't prove that every finite set is a null set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just as easily prove that a countably infinite set $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\}$ is null by putting an interval of width $\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$ about $a_n$.

The above paragraph assumed we were working in the reals, but a similar idea works for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: E.g., André's answer applies to the subset $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ consisting of all rational numbers  which might not "seem" to have measure zero. Furthermore, if you use the idea of André's answer, then you can construct an open set $U_{\epsilon}\supseteq \mathbb{Q}$ such that the measure of $U_{\epsilon}$ is less than $\epsilon$. (Why?) So, in fact, you can construct arbitrarily "measure-theoretically small" dense open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$! (Measure theory admits plenty of interesting examples such as this one; unlike point-set topology such examples can occur in $\mathbb{R}$!)

Answer (score 2):

It follows from countable sub additivity of the outer measure and the fact a single point set is null. This comes from the fact it can be covered by a single interval (x - r , x + r) for x being the element of the set, r being any positive number.